# angular 2 async route module + entryComponents

Tags: angular2-routing

I have an async loaded module with async route functionallity in angular 2. In the main module I have an implementation which uses the component factory to instantiate the component I added to the async module with entryComponents.

When I now try to instantiate it, I get the following error:

```
Error: No component factory found for InEntryComponentsComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
    at NoComponentFactoryError.ZoneAwareError (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.dll.js:4731:33)
    at NoComponentFactoryError.BaseError [as constructor] (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:28595:16)
    at new NoComponentFactoryError (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:28716:16)
    at _NullComponentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:28733:15)
    at AppModuleInjector.CodegenComponentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:28777:35)
    at SwapComponentDirective.set [as swapCmp] (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:2959:66)
    at Wrapper_SwapComponentDirective.check_swapCmp (/ModalModule/SwapComponentDirective/wrapper.ngfactory.js:50:26)
    at View_ModalOverlay2.detectChangesInternal (/ModalModule/ModalOverlay/component.ngfactory.js:83:36)
    at View_ModalOverlay2.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:79810:14)
    at View_ModalOverlay2.DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:80005:44)
    at ViewContainer.detectChangesInNestedViews (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:80143:37)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_ModalOverlay_Host0.detectChangesInternal (/ModalModule/ModalOverlay/host.ngfactory.js:32:14)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:79810:14)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:80005:44)
    at ViewContainer.detectChangesInNestedViews (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:80143:37)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_AppComponent_Host0.detectChangesInternal (/AppModule/AppComponent/host.ngfactory.js:31:14)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:79810:14)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:80005:44)
    at ViewRef_.detectChanges (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:59572:20)
    at http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:40308:67
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at ApplicationRef_.tick (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:40308:25)
    at http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:40227:105
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.dll.js:4162:26)
    at Object.onInvoke (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:30260:37)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.dll.js:4161:32)
    at Zone.run (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.dll.js:4033:43)
    at NgZone.run (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:30129:62)
    at Object.next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:40227:81)
    at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:42094:52)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:591:16)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:540:22)
    at Subscriber._next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:493:26)
    at Subscriber.next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:457:18)
    at EventEmitter.Subject.next (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:4237:25)
    at EventEmitter.emit (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:42080:76)
    at NgZone.checkStable (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:30225:40)
    at NgZone.onLeave (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:30301:14)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (http://localhost:3000/vendor.dll.js:30254:27)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.dll.js:4194:40)
    at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.dll.js:4071:47)
    at HTMLButtonElement.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:3000/polyfills.dll.js:4265:33)
```

Anyone an idea how to get this running? When I move the component to a module which is not async loaded, then all is fine.

As a base I'm using the angular2-webpack-starter.

Comment: Have you exported the component as well?

Comment: Yes, and I added to the declarations of the async module too.

Comment: Did you add to exports as well?

Comment: Yeah, in declarations, exports and entryComponents.

Comment: I'm using angular 2.4.6